# Appending to a text area followed by a new line

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to append a string to a text area, followed by a new line.

My research shows that 
Here's what I've tried thus far, but have not had any luck with:

```
function putStr(str){
    document.getElementById('output').value += str +\n;
}


function putStr(str){
    document.getElementById('output').value += str \n;
}

function putStr(str){
    document.getElementById('output').value += str;
    document.getElementById('output').value += \n;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a go with the quotes

```
function putStr(str){
   document.getElementById('output').value += str +"\n";
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DeanWhitehouse/xk4W3/

Comment: You beat me by 5 seconds haha. Impressive.

Answer (score 1):

put your new line in a string, since it's not a variable.

```
function putStr(str){
    document.getElementById('output').value += str + '\n';
}
```

Comment: Blah, I figured it was a noob mistake. Cheers!

Comment: Yes yes, will do, there's just that pesky accept answer timer I'm waiting for.